# How to disable/hide Legal policies, Tools from footer in this Image in Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, footer

I have this footer in my sharepoint site left bottom section, it is visible everywhere. I want to hide it or disable it. I don't know how and from where this came, and not sure how to control this.

[image]

Please let me know how to disable this footer

Comment: You can stop footer visibility from "Change the look" -> "Footer" in site. You can find "Change the look" option under "Settings" - gear icon in top right bar.

Comment: I don't see any settings

Answer (score 0):

The OOB SharePoint footer looks like this in communication sites:

[image]

From your screenshot, it is more relevant to the site design solution in your sharepoint website.

Please create a new team site in SharePoint start page to check whether the footer still exists.